# Make a sub menu

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to combine my two entries in a new submenu

I have this

```
<li class="dropdown" ng-controller="MenuPropertiesCtrl">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Properties <span
          class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
      style="width: 450px !important">
      <li><a href="" ng-click="open_create_properties_dialog()">Creer</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="open_compare_properties_dialog()">Comparer properties par versions</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="open_compare_properties_plateformes_dialog()">Comparer properties par plateformes</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I have this

```
Properties
|
|_Creer
|
|_Comparer properties par versions
|
|_Comparer properties par plateformes
```

So i want to do this ..?

```
Properties
|
|_Creer
|
|__Comparer
    |
    |_Comparer properties par versions
    |
    |_Comparer properties par plateformes
```

[Example in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ktn1ooz/2/)

Comment: Could you provide us jsfiddle? thanks :)

Comment: @MikeAnte http://jsfiddle.net/1ktn1ooz/2/

Answer (score 0):

you are using the bootstrap make easily drop dun menu. put this html script in your menu

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>         
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

and more info to refer this link http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav